# How to not make a method calling itself flood the stack

Tags: java, command-line-interface

im making a CLI. Depending on the input the appropriate method will be called rendering it's menu and performing some action or logic.

E.g. If I am in one of the menus I can decide to see all the members in 2 different ways. After my input and it has shown all the members. The method will call it self to render the menu again allowing for new input if the user wants to see the menu in any other way or exit.

But this makes the stack get new frames until the user exits this menu and goes back to the main menu.
How can I solve this without flooding the stack in a good way

I tried using while loops, but since some menus are nested it made 3 nested while loops. Where a new one started looping while I was in a nested menu.

```
public void viewMembersMenuSelection(int choice) {
    if (choice == '1') {
        System.out.println("Print verbose");
        printViewMembersMenu();
        viewMembersMenuSelection(getInputChar());
    }
    else if (choice == '2') {
        System.out.println("print compact");
        printViewMembersMenu();
        viewMembersMenuSelection(getInputChar());
    }
    else if (choice == '3') {
        System.out.println("exit to menu");
        printMainMenu();
        mainMenuSelection(getInputChar());
    }
}
```

`getInputChar()` gets the input and.

Comment: Seems to me that this could just be a loop that exits when `choice` is something other than '1', '2' or '3'.  Since nothing is done upon return from the recursive call, I don't see why there would be any difference if you just looped.  Basically, the stack is not saving any state in this case.

Comment: I ended up having multiple while loops because some menus were nested. I don't think that is very good either

Comment: Please show that and explain what problem you see with it.

Comment: I have only heard that generally it is better if you can avoid nestling while loops. I don't know why it would be bad or good

Comment: You could ask a separate question on that. Meanwhile try it and look for problems in your case. Nested loops with cleanly designed conditions is probably the core mechanism of 9 of 10 of the first 50 homework assignments in a programming class. All those "pyramids", "rectangle patterns" etc....